# in bash script, see and use the exact entire command line

Tags: bash, command-line, parameters

Is there any way to access the exact command line as typed?

(After variable expansion is OK)

It's the only way I can think of to achieve the following:

```
myscript.sh file1 file2 file3 -m"A multi word comment" [other parameters/options]
```

-- and inside the script we effectively call --

```
svn commit file1 file2 file3 -m"A multi word comment" [other parameters/options]
```

-- without having to duplicate all the parsing that svn does itself, just to make sense of the command line

(The problem I have is that in the example, $4 is going to be "-mA multi word comment" which is going to be a mess to sort out. I'd rather be able to shoot the whole command-line, quotes and all, straight to svn just exactly how svn will want to see it.)

If anyone knows a better way to write an svn "wrapper", I'd also like to hear it.

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried in your script:

```
svn commit "$@"
```

**Explanation:**

- `$@` is a special variable that containing all the arguments to the shell, starting at $1.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf edited: is there any reason for that aside from the notes listed here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html ?

Comment: My only reference for `bash` is the reference manual. See the corresponding section in this link: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters . As you will see, `"$*"` expands to a single word, and `$*` is just unusable with spaces. `"$*"` has some uses though, sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Inside effectively call you can:

```
svn commit "$@"
```

As for seeing exactly how it is typed — no. You can't tell `a b` from `a  b` (note one and two spaces between parameters — argh, I think even SO hides the second space ;)). But you don't need to.

Comment: thanks, yes all true -- my mistake was to think there would be a difference between `-m"multi word comment"` and `"-mmulti word comment"` but in effect, there doesn't seem to be -- svn works with both

Comment: Yes, effectively, `svn` gets the same string for `"-mmulti word"`, `-m"multi word"` and `-mmulti\ word`.

Answer (score 0):

if the script itself doesn't need the params, another way is to use alias, like this

```
alias commit='code_check && svn ci'
```

(where code_check is the script or function to execute before the svn commit)

you can then call

```
commit file1 file2 file3 -m"A multi word comment" [other parameters/options]
```

and the alias expansion turns the line into

```
code_check && svn ci file1 file2 file3 -m"A multi word comment" [other parameters/options]
```